# Spring Batch reader for temp table (create and insert) and stored procedure execution combination

Tags: spring-batch, multiple-tables

I am creating a spring batch application to migrate the data from legacy Sybase database to csv files which can be loaded into target systems.

I am facing problem in designing reader configuration.

Possible combination of inputs for reader:

1. Direct SQL query (JdbcCursorReader is suitable) - **No issues**
2. Stored Procedure (stored procedure reader is suitable) - **No issues**
3. Sequence of below steps execution to get input - **My Problem**

   - Create temp table
   - Insert values into temp table
   - Execute stored procedure (reads input from temp table, process them and write output into same temp table)
   - Read data from the inserted temp table

I am blocked with this requirement #3, kindly help me with the solution.

Note: I am doing Spring boot application with dynamic configuration for Spring Batch.

```
ItemReader<TreeMap<Integer, TableColumn>> itemReader = ReaderBuilder.getReader(sybaseDataSource, sybaseJdbcTemplate, workflowBean);

ItemProcessor<TreeMap<Integer, TableColumn>, TreeMap<Integer, TableColumn>> itemProcessor = ProcessorBuilder.getProcessor(workflowBean);

ItemWriter<TreeMap<Integer, TableColumn>> itemWriter = WriterBuilder.getWriter(workflowBean);

JobCompletionNotificationListener listener = new JobCompletionNotificationListener();

SimpleStepBuilder<TreeMap<Integer, TableColumn>, TreeMap<Integer, TableColumn>> stepBuilder = stepBuilderFactory
        .get(CommonJobEnum.SBTCH_JOB_STEP_COMMON_NAME.getValue()).allowStartIfComplete(true)

        .<TreeMap<Integer, TableColumn>, TreeMap<Integer, TableColumn>>chunk(10000).reader(itemReader);

if (itemProcessor != null) {
    stepBuilder.processor(itemProcessor);
}

Step step = stepBuilder.writer(itemWriter).build();

String jobName = workflowBean.getiMTWorkflowTemplate().getNameWflTemplate() + workflowBean.getIdWorkflow();
job = jobBuilderFactory.get(jobName).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener).flow(step).end().build();

jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

'Sybase' was the name of a company (which was bought out by SAP several years ago).  There were (at least) 4 different database products produced under the Sybase name ... Adaptiver Server Enterprise (ASE), SQL Anywhere, IQ, Advantage DB.

It would help if you state which Sybase database product you're trying to extract data from.

---

Assuming you're talking about ASE ...

If all you need to do is pull data out of Sybase tables then why jump through all the hoops of writing SQL, procs, Spring code, etc? Or is this some sort of homework assignment (but even so, why go this route)?

Just use bcp (OS-level utility that comes with the Sybase dataserver) to pull the data from your Sybase tables.  With a couple command line flags you can tell bcp to write the data to a delimited file.

Comment: Hi markp, thanks for your reply. Yes ASE. I am developing a dynamic ETL tool (requirement) which receives input (from some setup tables) as sql (with/without params), stored proc name (with/without params/criteria), multi-sql + store proc execution with multiple resultset etc. all these possible combinations. BCP is not suitable for us. So we are focusing on above approach. pls throw some lights if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you will have issues accessing a temporary table within a stored procedure that is created outside a stored procedure because the stored proc runs as the writer of the proc, not the executer. So the temp table doesn't belong to and is not visible to the writer of the proc so it can't access it.
You could either create the temp table within the proc, or use a permanent table and either lock the table when you are using it for this, or create a key on the table which you pass into the proc so it only processes the data you have just passed in.